# Component inside other component not clickable

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a detailspage in my RN app with a component called imagescrollview https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-header-scroll-view and i want the header image to be a swipable slideshow and I found this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider and i am trying to include it into the renderHeader function of the first package.

But the problem is that the slideshow is not clickable because it is inside the headerimagescrollview.

i've tried to set the imageSlider with zIndex: 1 but that doesn't help, i cant set the position to absolute because the image will dissapear.

```
<HeaderImageScrollView
                        maxHeight={180}
                        minHeight={80}
                        fadeOutForeground
                        maxOverlayOpacity={0.5}
                        minOverlayOpacity={0.0}
                        renderHeader={() => (
                            <ImageSlider
                                images={[
                                    ActivityFoto + this.state.dataSource.Foto,
                                    'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                                    'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any'
                                ]}
                            />
                        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to wrap the components with a `touchableOpacity`. I've a similar case but i'm using `react-native-snap-carousel` and it's working fine with the `touchableOpacity`

Comment: that could work but how do i route the image viewer button detectors to the touchableopacity onpress?

Comment: The problem is that the HeaderImageScrollView eats the onPress of the ImageSlider?

Comment: yes it is, the headerImageScrollView is blocking the onpress of the ImageSlider

Comment: I see that there are other issues in the HeaderImageScrollView component. Try to check if the <TouchableOpacity/> works, even if you cant differentiate it for the single images, just to check if you can create a click into that render component

Answer (score 0):

Use keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' in all of the click enabled parent (scrollView/Flatlist/TouchableOpacity etc)components then it will work.